# What does ECC stand for in the image and how to remove it?

Tags: phone-app

What does ECC stand for in the image and how to remove it ?

[image: dialer snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

ECC stands for Emergency call codes like police station, ambulance, etc.

It is even available when you are locked down and if it annoys you then you can remove it by installing different screen locks like

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pandasoft.unloacker.drawinglockscreen&hl=en

Comment: How did it come in the first place..it wasn't there earlier !!

Comment: Because you might have changed the lock screen recently. For example check this  http://img.tapatalk.com/d/13/10/26/y7e9ujet.jpg